# Matplotlib how to plot in two y axis

Tags: matplotlib

I have tried the following code, try to plot two curves in two axis and one graph. But I can only see one curve, anything I did wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt            
PlotFigure_1 = plt.figure()            
ax1 = PlotFigure_1.add_subplot(111)
par1 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.cla()
par1.cla()  
x=[1, 2, 3, 4]
y=[1, 2, 3, 5]
ax1.plot(x, y, 'r')
x1=[1, 2, 3, 4]
y1=[10, 20, 30, 50]
par1.plot(x1, y1, 'b')
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75) # was 0.7 try 
plt.show()
```

Comment: What happens if you do `ax1.set_ylim(0, 10)`?

Comment: Thanks for the help bnaecker, this is simply hidden one behind the other.

Comment: You're welcome. It's good practice to mark the answer as accepted if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line is just hidden behind the second.

Because `y1 == 10 * y`, the curves have the same "shape". But each y-axis is scaled independently, so the curves lie in the same position *relative* to their respective axes. The data differs by a factor of 10, but so does the extent of their y-axes, i.e., `par1.get_ylim() == 10 * ax1.get_ylim()`.

To prove this to yourself, you can:

1. Force the axes to have different extents relative to their data, e.g., by doing `ax1.set_ylim(0, 6)`.
2. Plot data in each axes where there is a different linear factor for at least some of the points (e.g., use `y1 = [10, 20, 30, 60]`).